# Custom Controller path issue magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

Whats wrong in my URl below.

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('test/manageRecipe/index') ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" autocomplete="off">

    <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add New Recipe') ?>">
        <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add New Recipe') ?></span></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

I have a button, on a click of it, it should redirect to my Controller - ManageRecipeController.php

```
class Vendor_Test_ManageRecipeController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'Manage';
    }
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <vendor_recipe>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>vendor_Recipe</module>
                <frontName>vendor_recipe</frontName>
            </args>
        </vendor_recipe>
    </routers>

</frontend>
```

Comment: please provide your config.xml frontend route part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `manageRecipe`. this will be your url

`echo $this->getUrl('vendor_recipe/manageRecipe/index')`

Comment: Please check my original code which i tried, i cleared cache still not working

Comment: did you define the frontName? can you add your `config.xml` too

Comment: @SachinS updated the code

Answer (score 1):

You have to try with below action,

**Replace testcustomcontroller with testcustom**

```
echo $this->getUrl('recipe/manageRecipe/index')
```

You have to define inside config.xml file,

```
  <frontend>
    <routers>
        <recipe>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Vendor_Recipe</module>
                <frontName>recipe</frontName>
            </args>
        </recipe>
    </routers>

</frontend>
```

where **Vendor_Modulename** is replaced with your custom modulename.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, sorry my url was test/testcustom/index itself in my code, while copying i added test/testcustomcontroller/index... even for test/testcustom/index  i get 404

Comment: check with test/testCustom/index

Comment: Pls check the updated code..

Comment: added config router

Comment: Please check updated answer

Comment: Ok thanks, got it..mistake was with my url full path...

Answer (score 1):

after looking your code your URL should be

```
echo $this->getUrl('vendor_recipe/manageRecipe/index')
```

it should be `base_url+frontName+controllerName+ActionName`

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be in the form action because of the object which is being assigned to $this in the phtml file. It would be better to us the following line of code for extracting the action for the form

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/manageRecipe/index')?>
```

The * indicates the current module from which the form has been rendered.